# How to find out if conda is already available on a machine within a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, anaconda, conda

I want to create a bash script to install a new virtual environment "ABC" in conda. But before I go ahead and run a command to create this env, I want to check if conda is already installed on the machine. If not installed, I want to install miniconda and then create the env "ABC". If conda is already installed then I would just go ahead and create the environment. (All this should happen within the same script)
I just want to know if it is possible to check the existence of conda within a bash script and then proceed with the rest of the installations?

'''

```
#!/bin/bash
<code_to_check_existence_of_conda_env_here ?>
//If it does not exist, I will run the below code
mkdir -p miniconda3
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O 
miniconda3/miniconda.sh
bash miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3
conda env update -f my_env.yml
```

'''

Comment: The `Anaconda3` ? should be within your `PATH` if it is installed.

Comment: It could be installed anywhere. Knowing whether and where it is installed should be a prerequisite for running your script, not something your script tries to manage. (This is what package managers were invented to solve.)

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that Conda has multiple components. Which components are loaded depends on the how Conda is installed and what user the BASH script is executing under. I'll try describing the components and hopefully you can decide what is suitable to verify.

## Conda Components

### 1: Conda Package

The first is a Python package `conda`, which is installed in the Anaconda/Miniconda/Miniforge **base** environment. *If the **base** environment is activated*, one could test

```
python -m conda
```

which will give something like

```
/path/to/python: No module named conda
```

if it isn't there. Otherwise, it outputs the `conda` entrypoint's documentation.

### 2: Conda Entrypoint

The entrypoint `conda`, which acts as a CLI, is located under the `condabin` directory of the Anaconda/Miniconda/Miniforge installation. When a user runs `conda init`, a managed section is added to their shell initialization file (`.bashrc` for Linux BASH), that includes code to add the `condabin` to PATH. This is most likely what OP wants to identify, however, running with the shebang `/bin/bash` will not load the `.bashrc` file. Instead, one should probably be using

```
#!/bin/bash -l
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -l
```

Then the entrypoint can be located with

```
which conda
```

### 3: Conda Activate

Finally, Conda also includes some shell-only functions, which are defined in the aforementioned shell initialization code. This sets up a middleman shell function, also called `conda` (essentially an alias), which can be viewed with

```
type conda
```

This function serves to determine whether the `conda (de)?activate` commands are being requested, which are pure shell functions, or something that needs to be forwarded to the entrypoint.

## Recommendation

Were I designing this, I would write an *interactive* script that checks for #2 (`which conda`) and if that comes up blank then *prompt the user* to either provide the PATH to the Conda entrypoint (maybe they installed it in a weird place or didn't run `conda init`) or install Miniforge.<sup>**1**</sup>

I also would not use the **base** environment to install stuff - that is a bad idea for an end-user, let alone a third-party - and instead create a new environment. I would prompt the user with a specific default environment name, but also provide an option for them to customize.

---

**[1]** Yes, Miniforge, not Miniconda. Commercial use of the Anaconda **defaults** channels now requires a paid license, so better to use the free Miniforge.

Comment: In some setups, conda is present, but not initialized and hence not functional. This is for example the case in pyenv, with a conda environment installed, but not activated. In that case, `type conda` returns "conda is /opt/pyenv/shims/conda" (or similar). In this scenario, I'd rather rely on shell flags that are set *after* conda is initialized. I think the variable `$CONDA_SHLVL` or `CONDA_EXE` are such candidates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good at bash scripting but I would execute a command:

```
pip3 freeze | grep conda
```

and based on the output (if exit status was an error or not) install it or directly create the environment.

Comment: But conda is not a part of pip freeze. It's not a package within python.

Answer (score 0):

run the command `conda list` on your machine, the output will of be different when its installed vs not installed, then run if statement on the output.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, if we want to check if a software is installed or not, the following check is used.

```
if dpkg -l $SOFTWARE; then
<Do stuff>
```

Comment: This is a nice suggestion. But unfortunately I do not see conda in the dpkg list :(

Comment: Are conda commands like 'conda list' etc working from your terminal?

Answer (score 0):

### ensureconda

This sounds like the intended problem that [the experimental tool `ensureconda`](https://github.com/conda-incubator/ensureconda) was designed to solve. This, however, requires a Python installation with pip:

```bash
pip install ensureconda
```

Here are the command options:

```txt
$ ensureconda --help
Usage: ensureconda [OPTIONS]

  Ensures that a conda/mamba is installed.

Options:
  --mamba / --no-mamba            search for mamba
  --micromamba / --no-micromamba  search for micromamba, install if not
                                  present
  --conda / --no-conda            search for conda
  --conda-exe / --no-conda-exe    search for conda.exe / conda-standalone,
                                  install if not present
  --no-install                    don't install conda/mamba if no version can
                                  be discovered
  --min-conda-version VERSIONNUMBER
                                  minimum version of conda to accept (defaults
                                  to 4.8.2)
  --min-mamba-version VERSIONNUMBER
                                  minimum version of mamba/micromamba to
                                  accept (defaults to 0.7.3)
  --help                          Show this message and exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `conda activate`
or `conda activate env_name`

The first command will activate the base environment if it is already installed. The second command will do activate the user created environment if it is installed.