# Conda Create Environment - No Compatible Shell found

Tags: bash, conda, miniconda

I have a bash script where i will be creating conda virtual environment and install packages into it.
currently we are using conda version 4.5.12 with python 3.6 in my virtual environment.

Am trying to upgrade conda version to 4.9.2 with python 3.6.

```
conda --version
   4.9.2
```

This is the command i use inside my script

```
conda create -y --name virtual_env python=3.6
```

This Runs and fails during Download and Extracting Packages Step. Below is the Error Report

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/project/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/project/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/root/project/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/root/project/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 41, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'create')
  File "/root/project/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 317, in install
    handle_txn(unlink_link_transaction, prefix, args, newenv)
  File "/root/project/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 346, in handle_txn
    unlink_link_transaction.execute()
  File "/root/project/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 249, in execute
    self._execute(tuple(concat(interleave(itervalues(self.prefix_action_groups)))))
  File "/root/project/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 712, in _execute
    raise CondaMultiError(tuple(concatv(
conda.CondaMultiError: No compatible shell found!
()
```

Experts Please help.

Adding briefs of the script

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

install_conda_for_linux(){
        #
        # Determine Installation Location for non Windows systems
        #
        #Get path where miniconda needs to get installed and remove if anything exixsts already#
        
        downloaded_file=$base_dir/$conda_file
        output_formatted Removing file: $downloaded_file
        rm -f $downloaded_file

        #
        # Download Miniconda
        #
        output_formatted Downloading Miniconda from: $conda_url '\n' Saving file in: $base_dir

        curl -L $conda_url > $base_dir/$conda_file
       
        #
        # Install Miniconda
        #
        rm -rf $install_dir

        bash $base_dir/$conda_file -b -p $install_dir

        #
        # Modify PATH
        #
        conda_path=$install_dir/bin
        export PATH=$conda_path:\$PATH

        conda_version=`conda --version`
       
}


#
# Variables
#

pyversion=3
python_version="3.6.10"
conda_version="4.9.2"
skip_install=$1
base_url='https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda'
virtual_env=venv


#conda_file is only specified for use in messages below on Windows, as it is manual install, which must be done before running this script.
declare -A conda_file_map
conda_file_map[Linux]="Miniconda${pyversion}-py39_${conda_version}-Linux-x86_64.sh"


conda_file=${conda_file_map[${os_type}]}

#
# Installation of conda and its dependencies
#

if [ ${skip_install} != 'true' ];then

    conda_url=${base_url}/${conda_file}

    install_conda_for_linux


    #
    # Create Environment
    #

    output_formatted Creating new virtual environment: $virtual_env for python_version $python_version

    conda create -y -vv --name $virtual_env python=$python_version
```

Comment: Sounds like this is a BASH question, not a Python one (the Python is simply incidental to Conda). Please include the shebang of your BASH script and the exact command you use to run the script.

Comment: @merv, is `conda` a shell function or an executable with its own shebang? If the latter, the identity of the shell _invoking_ `conda` shouldn't matter.

Comment: Anyhow -- per https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7dbd2729e4916446da65dacb444a9d33e6f8f355/conda/utils.py#L388-L390, this is caused by a PATH that includes neither `bash` or `sh`.

Comment: @saravankumar, can you provide enough of a [mre] to let someone else see the problem themselves? Maybe there's surrounding code that changes the PATH (whether intentionally or otherwise), maybe you're running this in a Docker container with a minimal software loadout -- whatever the environment is, enough details to let someone else see the problem should be included in the question itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy [Conda has multiple components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68062665/570918). The default (recommended) interface is a shell function (see `type conda`), that case-wise invokes a Python entrypoint by the name `conda` (see `which conda`), and that does have its own shebang pointing to the **base** environment's Python. Since Conda is clearly getting into the Python portion of execution, I think you're right that the shell doesn't matter.

Comment: This is the Shebang of the script am using #!/bin/bash. which bash /usr/bin/bash, which sh /usr/bin/sh

Comment: All i doubt is how does the same script works when i use 4.5.12 version of conda with python 3.6 and not for 4.9.2 with python 3.6. Is it like conda and python versions doesn't match or something?

Comment: Hmm. You repeatedly mention Python 3.6, but Conda is clearly running in a Python 3.9 interpreter according to the error. Are you installing multiple instances of Miniconda?

Comment: In my machine in another directory. Yes i do have another version of miniconda. @merv Conda 4.9.2 has 3.9 in built. i guess that is why it shows 3.9. One more thing, i figured out its not only about 3.6. Whatever the version i provide it throws same error.

Comment: @merv & Charles Duffy, Once the script runs and when it reaches conda create environment, it fails with the above error as i mentioned. But then i tried using conda create environment command manually post the failure. It worked. It fails from Bash script but succeeds when ran manually.

Comment: @saravankumar, again, check how the PATH is set at the time of the failure. `python -i yourscript` for example will drop you to an interactive shell when the script exits, so you can check `os.environ['PATH']` from there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, Let me get back to you with those details.

Comment: Ahh. `export PATH=$conda_path:\$PATH` needs to be `PATH=$conda_path:$PATH`. The most important change is taking out the backslash, but the `export` is also both unnecessary and undesirable (all updates to things that are environment variables are automatically exported _no matter what_, and using the `export` command sends one down a more complicated path in the parser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your bug:

```
conda_path=$install_dir/bin
export PATH=$conda_path:\$PATH
```

Let's say `install_dir=/path/to/install`, and the starting value of `PATH` is `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` (which is how `which sh` finds `/bin/sh` or `/usr/bin/sh`).

After you ran this command, because of the backslash, you *don't* have `PATH=/path/to/install/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` (which is what you want), but instead you have `PATH=/path/to/install/bin:$PATH`; the backslash caused the *literal string `$PATH`* to be added to your variable, instead of the string that's contained therein.

Thus, `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are no longer listed in your `PATH` variable, so `which` can't find them.

---

To fix this, just make it:

```
conda_path=$install_dir/bin
PATH=$conda_path:$PATH
```

The big fix is changing `\$PATH` to just `$PATH` -- but beyond that, you don't need the `export` (changes to variables that are already in the environment are automatically re-exported), and having it adds complexity for no good reason.

Comment: Thank you @Charles Duffy. This helps me for sure.

Comment: @saravankumar If this answers your question, click the checkbox next to your answer; accepting an answer in this way will mark your question solved.